# Dired: group directories and symlinks to directories first

Tags: dired

Is there a way to make dired group directories *and symlinks to directories* first?

If I add --group-directories, like this:

```
(setq dired-listing-switches "--group-directories-first -al")
```

then it groups directories first, but symlinks still get sorted under files.

If I also add --dereference, like:

```
(setq dired-listing-switches "--group-directories-first --dereference -al")
```

then symlinks get resolved, and the directories do all show up together. But there's no indication anymore that they are symlinks anymore. I'd like them to be still displayed as symlinks, but get grouped first too.

Comment: Note that some `ls` versions do not support the `--group-directories-first` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is what you get if you load standard library **`ls-lisp.el`** and you customize option **`ls-lisp-dirs-first`** to non-`nil`.

(If the value of option `ls-lisp-emulation` is `MS-Windows` then `ls-lisp-dirs-first` is non-`nil` by default.  This is the case if you use Emacs on MS Windows, but you can set it this way on any platform.)

If you also use library [Dired Sort Menu](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredSortMenu) then you get a `S-mouse-2` popup menu in Dired (and a menu-bar menu) that provides all of the `ls-lisp.el` sorting possibilities.

Comment: Thanks! That does work, but ls-lisp seems to lack a "-v" flag to sort numbers naturally (ie 1 2 10 instead of 1 10 2). I guess I could hack that in, but ls-lisp is also noticeably slower, so it'd be easier to use a modified ls instead. (It does bother me in ls too, after all, so that might just be the better choice.)

Comment: Yes, ls-lisp is coded in Lisp, so it can be slower. Yes, it does not support all of the switches of all versions of `ls`. Remember too that you can define your own commands that call other commands, and some of those can explicitly make use of ls-lisp. IOW, you can mix and match. You need load ls-lisp only once (in any of those commands: `(require 'ls-lisp)`. Then bind variable `ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program` as needed, to get the `ls` behavior you want: from `ls` or from ls-lisp.

Comment: I gave the `ls` patch a try and posted that as an answer as well. Your answer is probably the better one in general because it's portable, more straightforward and directly answers the question. I would've probably just used `ls-lisp` as a "good enough" solution if it supported `-v` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `ls-lisp` solution is portable and straightforward, but unfortunately lacks some important (to me) flags and is considerably slower.

So instead, one can also modify `ls` directly. Because I wanted the same feature in `ls` in the terminal anyway, [I wrote a patch for the `ls` in GNU's coreutils](https://github.com/muflax/coreutils/tree/ls-dirs). That's certainly a lot less portable, but it was a much smaller and more desirable change than extending `ls-lisp` with the missing flags. (Still, `ls-lisp` can be used as a fallback as well.)

This patch for coreutils (8.25) sorts symlinked directories like directories when `--group-directories-first` is provided:

```
diff --git a/src/ls.c b/src/ls.c
index 3572060..8dd6395 100644
--- a/src/ls.c
+++ b/src/ls.c
@@ -2969,10 +2969,10 @@ gobble_file (char const *name, enum filetype type, ino_t inode,
               || is_colored (C_STICKY_OTHER_WRITABLE)))
       /* When dereferencing symlinks, the inode and type must come from
          stat, but readdir provides the inode and type of lstat.  */
-      || ((print_inode || format_needs_type)
+      || ((print_inode || format_needs_type || directories_first)
           && (type == symbolic_link || type == unknown)
           && (dereference == DEREF_ALWAYS
-              || color_symlink_as_referent || check_symlink_color))
+              || color_symlink_as_referent || check_symlink_color || directories_first))
       /* Command line dereferences are already taken care of by the above
          assertion that the inode number is not yet known.  */
       || (print_inode && inode == NOT_AN_INODE_NUMBER)
@@ -3113,7 +3113,7 @@ gobble_file (char const *name, enum filetype type, ino_t inode,
         }

       if (S_ISLNK (f->stat.st_mode)
-          && (format == long_format || check_symlink_color))
+          && (format == long_format || check_symlink_color || directories_first))
         {
           struct stat linkstats;

@@ -3123,7 +3123,7 @@ gobble_file (char const *name, enum filetype type, ino_t inode,
           /* Avoid following symbolic links when possible, ie, when
              they won't be traced and when no indicator is needed.  */
           if (linkname
-              && (file_type <= indicator_style || check_symlink_color)
+              && (file_type <= indicator_style || check_symlink_color || directories_first)
               && stat (linkname, &linkstats) == 0)
             {
               f->linkok = true;
@@ -3131,7 +3131,7 @@ gobble_file (char const *name, enum filetype type, ino_t inode,
               /* Symbolic links to directories that are mentioned on the
                  command line are automatically traced if not being
                  listed as files.  */
-              if (!command_line_arg || format == long_format
+              if (!command_line_arg || format == long_format || directories_first
                   || !S_ISDIR (linkstats.st_mode))
                 {
                   /* Get the linked-to file's mode for the filetype indicator
@@ -3251,6 +3251,15 @@ is_directory (const struct fileinfo *f)
   return f->filetype == directory || f->filetype == arg_directory;
 }

+/* Return true if F refers to a directory or a symlink pointing at a directory.  */
+static bool
+is_directory_or_symlink_to_directory (const struct fileinfo *f)
+{
+  return f->filetype == directory
+    || f->filetype == arg_directory
+    || (f->filetype == symbolic_link && S_ISDIR(f->linkmode));
+}
+
 /* Put the name of the file that FILENAME is a symbolic link to
    into the LINKNAME field of 'f'.  COMMAND_LINE_ARG indicates whether
    FILENAME is a command-line argument.  */
@@ -3396,8 +3405,8 @@ typedef int (*qsortFunc)(V a, V b);
 #define DIRFIRST_CHECK(a, b)                       \
   do                                   \
     {                                  \
-      bool a_is_dir = is_directory ((struct fileinfo const *) a);  \
-      bool b_is_dir = is_directory ((struct fileinfo const *) b);  \
+      bool a_is_dir = is_directory_or_symlink_to_directory ((struct fileinfo const *) a); \
+      bool b_is_dir = is_directory_or_symlink_to_directory ((struct fileinfo const *) b);  \
       if (a_is_dir && !b_is_dir)                   \
         return -1;         /* a goes before b */           \
       if (!a_is_dir && b_is_dir)                   \
```